# Unit testing whether or not method used in System.Threading.Timer constructor (TimerCallback) has been called using Moq

Tags: c#, timer, callback, moq

I am looking to make sure a callback passed into a System.Threading.Timer with TimerCallback in the signature:

[public Timer (System.Threading.TimerCallback callback, object? state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period);](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.timer.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-threading-timer-ctor(system-threading-timercallback-system-object-system-timespan-system-timespan))

I have a class holding a timer and need a way to make sure the callback (`MethodC`) has test coverage. Also, I am not going to wait 15 minutes to see what happens with `MethodC`.

```
using System.Threading;
public class MyClass
{
    private Timer? myTimer;

    public MyClass() { }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        MethodB();
    }

    private void MethodB()
    {
        myTimer = new Timer(
            MethodC, // TimerCallback
            new Object(),
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
        // do some things
    }

    private void MethodC(object? state)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Based on my search, it seems the answer is to move the timer to an interface and then mock interface. I am using Moq.
However, I am still missing some understanding of achieving my goal. I don't know how I can test `MethodC` if the callback is given in the constructor of `myTimer`.

I ultimately want to check if the code is reached with Moq's `Verify` and maybe other behavior.

I have tried to move timer code to an interface:

```
    interface ITimer
    {
        void SetTimer(TimerCallback callback, object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period);
        void Dispose();
    }

    class MyTimer : ITimer, IDisposable
    {
        private Timer timer;
        private TimerCallback callback;

        public MyTimer(TimerCallback callback, Object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period)
        {
            this.callback = callback;
            this.SetTimer(this.callback, state, dueTime, period);
        }

        public void SetTimer(TimerCallback callback, object state, TimeSpan dueTime, TimeSpan period)
        {
            this.timer = new Timer(callback, state, dueTime, period);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            timer.Dispose();
        }
    }


.......



using System.Threading;
public class MyClass : IDisposable {


  private ITimer myTimer;
  
  public MyClass(){}

  public void MethodA(){
    MethodB();
  }

  private void MethodB(){
    this.myTimer = new MyTimer(this.MethodC, // TimerCallback
                             new Object(), 
                             TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15), 
                             TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15))
    // do some things
  }

  private void MethodC(){
    // do something
  }
  
}
```

The timer callback is given to the `Timer` object through the constructor. There is no method to call, and therefore Moq's `Setup(Expression<Action<T>> expression)` doesn't seem to work here. After a certain amount of time is called, the callback `MethodC` is just called on another thread, also it is private.

I try to make my `MyTimer` class create the `Timer` in another method, however I want to test `MethodC`, not `SetTimer`.

The design seems convoluted and untestable. But I am also not that familiar with Moq. Is there some suggestion on how I can improve this, so that I can test `MethodC`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's trivially possible to write code that can't easily be tested. The OP is one such example. You should expect to have to modify the System Under Test (SUT) in some way in order to make it testable. Sometimes, this can lead to a more modular design in general, so this isn't necessarily a bad thing.

The simplest thing that immediately springs to mind is to first define an interface:

```
public interface ITimer
{
    void Start(
        TimerCallback callback,
        object? state,
        TimeSpan dueTime,
        TimeSpan period);
}
```

According to the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), one doesn't have to define more members with more details than the SUT needs, and in the case a method that looks like the constructor is enough.

Then modify the SUT to use Constructor Injection:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ITimer timer;

    public MyClass(ITimer timer)
    {
        this.timer = timer;
    }

    public void MethodA()
    {
        MethodB();
    }

    private void MethodB()
    {
        timer.Start(
            MethodC, // TimerCallback
            new Object(),
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
        // do some things
    }

    private void MethodC(object? state)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

You can now verify that the `Start` method gets called:

```
[Fact]
public void MethodAInvokesMethodC()
{
    var mockTimer = new Mock<ITimer>();
    var sut = new MyClass(mockTimer.Object);

    sut.MethodA();
    
    mockTimer.Verify(t => t.Start(
        It.IsAny<TimerCallback>(),
        It.IsAny<object>(),
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
        TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)));
}
```

If you also want to verify *which* method is designated as the callback, you *may* consider changing the *Verify* call to this:

```
mockTimer.Verify(t => t.Start(
    It.Is<TimerCallback>(cb => cb.Method.Name == "MethodC"),
    It.IsAny<object>(),
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)));
```

This, however, makes the test more brittle, because if you change the name of `MethodC`, this test is going to fail. Instead, consider making `MethodC` `public`:

```
public void MethodC(object? state)
{
    // do something
}
```

This then enables you to write the assertion like this:

```
mockTimer.Verify(t => t.Start(
    sut.MethodC,
    It.IsAny<object>(),
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
    TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15)));
```

Now that `MethodC` is `public` it also means that you can write tests against it, so making it `public` isn't necessarily a bad thing.

For production use, you can implement the interface using the real `Timer` class:

```
public sealed class TimerTimer : ITimer
{
    private Timer? timer;

    public void Start(
        TimerCallback callback,
        object? state,
        TimeSpan dueTime,
        TimeSpan period)
    {
        timer = new Timer(callback, state, dueTime, period);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to test what MethodC does, one option is to mark MethodC as `internal` rather than `private` then make internals visible to your unit test project. With .Net Core this is fairly simple, especially if you follow consistent conventions like using ProjectName.UnitTests.csproj for unit tests for a ProjectName.csproj project. The following group added to the ProjectName.csproj will allow unit test and integration test projects to see internals:

This can be helpful for cases where you have some logic that would benefit from a test that isn't public and not convenient to get to publicly. The caveat of this is that this is code specific for unit testing, which you should avoid as much as possible. However, I treat this as more of a guideline than a rule. If the benefit outweighs the smell compared to the cost of alternative re-factoring to try and remove all smells then it may be worth it. I do commonly have legitimate internals limited to an assembly that I want to test. An option to keep the method `private` where we don't want it possibly accessed as `internal` then you can use an internal test adapter:

```
private MethodC(/* parameters */) 
{
    // ...
}

internal MethodC_TestAdapter(/* parameters */)
{
#if TEST
     MethodC( /* parameters */ )
#else
     throw new InvalidOperation($"{nameof(MethodC_TestAdapter)} should never be called in non-testing code.");
#end if
}
```

where TEST is a pre-processor that should be defined only when running locally and unit testing configurations for automated builds. This way if a build gets made where someone later finds "MethodC_TestAdapter" in their intellisense and calls it, they should be greeted by an exception with an explanation.

That said, part of the challenge of writing highly test-able code is following good coding principles in how you structure the code. Ideally you would want to decouple state between MethodB and MethodC if MethodC is effectively a handler.
If MethodC alters common state within this class, that is a bit of a problem because it is a juggling situation about what that state might be at any given time and competition between updates made by Method C and other Methods that may execute. So for instance setting flags, incrementing or changing values, etc. If MethodC can be isolated as stateless or managing just its own state, then MethodC could be moved out into it's own Class where an instance can be constructed or injected into the class where MethodB lives. MethodB can establish a timer that links to the dependency instance MethodC. In this way MethodC on it's service can be tested for behaviour without worrying about access modifiers. Object oriented languages deal with state, but the goal is to compartmentalize it as much as possible.